# Getting event between actions user press call button and when user start hear call sounds

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I found 3 events in TelephonyManager, but how can I measure time that phone need to connect subscriber? Is it possible?

```
/** Device call state: No activity. */
    public static final int CALL_STATE_IDLE = 0;
    /** Device call state: Ringing. A new call arrived and is
     *  ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is
     *  already active. */
    public static final int CALL_STATE_RINGING = 1;
    /** Device call state: Off-hook. At least one call exists
      * that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing
      * or waiting. */
    public static final int CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK = 2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  There's no event broadcast for call connected, or call picked up.

Comment: Its possible for pre API 26 devices using `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: @Psypher Its possible to tell if there's an ongoing call.  Its not possible to tell if the other end has picked up, or if the call has connected (instead of merely being started).  There has never been an API for either of those.  When you make a call, it transitions directly to OFFHOOK, and there is no connected or picked up state.

Comment: Oh ya..thats true. No way to know its picked up in the other callers end